# Should we have a "comments are not for chat" rule?

Tags: discussion, rules, comments

This is inspired by a recent answer that [attracted a lot of comments](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-using-an-existing-ir-compiler-infrastructure-like-llvm/1830?noredirect=1#comment2850_1830).

I'm not accusing anyone of doing anything wrong; it was a good on-topic discussion. However, many SE sites have a rule to limit the number of comments because it can get unwieldy and doesn't fit with the question-and-answer format.

I don't think we can move comments to chat without moderators, but should we have a rule about taking extended comment threads to chat?

Comment: Is this not built into the SE site software? I think once a comment thread gets long enough, it will prompt with a link to continue in a new chat room.

Comment: But no one uses it is the issue @kaya3-supportthestrike

Comment: the primary point of comments is for the answer to eventually improve. One thing you should think to yourself is "is this chain of comments going to eventually turn into an improved answer?"

Answer (score 5):

We already do. First, you can click add comment and if the discussion is long enough it will prompt you to move it chat. If users continue the discussion on the post then yell at them/flag it. Second, flag the post "in need of mod intervention" and say "too many comments". Third, if its off topic or some comments have been resolved then flag as "no longer needed"

Comment: But is it a rule?

Comment: Yes it is @Pseudonym